# failure with belongs_to active record association - id returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec

I think I know what the problem is here, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

here are my `models`

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :student_groups
...
end
```

StudentGroup

```
class StudentGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :subjects
  has_many   :students

end
```

Subject

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :end_date, :name

  belongs_to :student_group
  belongs_to :student

end
```

Student

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gender, :name

  belongs_to :student_group
  has_many :subjects

end
```

in my `Student_Spec.rb` I have the following test **EDITED**:

```
...

before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  @student_group_attr = { name: "4a"}
  @student_group = @user.student_groups.create(@student_group_attr)
  @date = Date.today+180
  @subject_attr = { name: "English", end_date: @date}
end

...

describe "Student associations" do

  before(:each) do
    @subject = @student_group.subjects.create!(@subject_attr)
    @student_attr = { name: "Example Student", gender: "Female" }
    @student = @student_group.students.create(@student_attr) 
  end

  it "should have the right associated student" do
    @subject.student_id.should == @student.id
    @subject.student.should == @student
  end
end
```

I have the same test in other specs and it works fine - I checked it out in the console and got this:

```
2.0.0-p0 :015 > @subject
=> #<Subject id: 1, name: "English", student_group_id: 1, student_id: nil, end_date: "2013-11-18", created_at: "2013-05-22 15:08:44", updated_at: "2013-05-22 15:08:44">
```

So for whatever reason, the student_id isn't getting linked to the subject...what am I doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: Why would that subject be associated to that student? Are you expecting it to pick a student from the student group and assign that to the subject automatically?

Comment: Agreed with @FrederickCheung, the models have problem. No direct relation needed between subject and group. They already have the bridge "student".

Comment: ah, right.  so...should i be using a through association here?  Sorry, I'm bit confused by associations.  thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @BillyChan, So i should just take the student_id out all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Changed models to the following:

**student_groups.rb**

```
class StudentGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :students

end
```

**students.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gender, :name

  belongs_to :student_group
  has_many :subjects

end
```

**subject.rb**

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :end_date, :name

  belongs_to :student

end
```

And model specs to the following:

**student_group_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe StudentGroup do

  before(:each) do
    association_attr  
  end

  it "should create a new instance with valid attributes" do
    @user.student_groups.create!(@attr).should be_valid
  end

  describe "User associations" do

    it "should have a user attribute" do
      @student_group.should respond_to(:user)
    end

    it "should have the right associated user" do
      @student_group.user_id.should == @user.id
      @student_group.user.should == @user
    end

  end

  describe "Student associations" do

    it "should have a student attritube" do
      @student_group.should respond_to(:students)
    end

  end

end
```

**student_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Student do

  before(:each) do
    association_attr
  end

  it "should create a new instance with valid attributes" do
    @student_group.students.create!(@attr).should be_valid
  end

  describe "Student_Group associations" do

    it "should have a student_group attribute" do
      @student.should respond_to(:student_group)
    end

    it "should have the right associated student_group" do
      @student.student_group_id.should == @student_group.id
      @student.student_group.should == @student_group
    end

  end

  describe "Subject associations" do

    it "should have a subject attribute" do
      @student.should respond_to(:subjects)
    end

  end

end
```

**subject_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Subject do

  before(:each) do
    association_attr  
  end

  it "should create a new instance with valid attributes" do
    @student.subjects.create!(@subject_attr).should be_valid
  end

  describe "Student associations" do

    it "should have a student attribute" do
      @subject.should respond_to(:student)
    end

    it "should have the right associated student" do
      @subject.student_id.should == @student.id
      @subject.student.should == @student
    end 

  end

end
```

And finally changed **spec_helper.rb** as follows:

```
def association_attr
  # User attritbutes 
  @user = Factory(:user)

  # Student_group
  @student_group = @user.student_groups.create(@student_group_attr)
  # Student_group attributes
  @student_group_attr = { name: "4a"}

  # Student 
  @student = @student_group.students.create(@student_attr)
  # Student attributes
  @student_attr = { name: "Example Student", gender: "Transgender" }

  # Subject
  @subject = @student.subjects.create!(@subject_attr)
  # Subject attributes
  @subject_attr = { name: "English", end_date: @date}
  @date = Date.today+180
end
```

Thanks to [Frederick Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064226/frederick-cheung) and [Billy Chan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721198/billy-chan) for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Reload @subject, maybe its not loaded from the db and therefore its empty